# Material UI Time Picker UTC

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I've been looking through the docs and playing around on my own with material ui and I do not see any sort of setting to be able to choose the time in UTC. It always defaults to my local timezone for the time picker, even if I pass in a UTC Date object. Is anyone aware of a workaround for this?

Comment: I noticed that the same thing happens with the Date Picker as well. If, for example, you have a UTC time of June 24, 2016 at 01:45, it may be displayed as June 23, 2016 in the date picker depending on your time zone. Has anyone found a real workaround to this either?

Answer (score 2):

Only way is to format your Date into String then use moment-timezone

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");

var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");

var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");
```

I hope it will be support in material-ui