# Date picker: timezone shift

Tags: material-ui, admin-on-rest

#### Problem

If I select a date in a `<DateInput>`, the datetime is in the user's timezone (e.g. *2017-07-01T00:00:00.000+02:00*) but when it's sent to the server, it's transformed to UTC and thus ends up as *2017-06-30T22:00:00.000Z*, one day behind.

The underlaying back-end is unaware of the user's timezone and cannot shift the dates back so after stripping the time it ends up with wrong date.

#### What would solve my problem

Any of these options would work fine:

1. The datetime is sent with the user's timezone.
2. The datetime is sent as naive (=without timezone).
3. The date selected by the user is already treated as UTC.
4. A date only (*2017-07-01*) instead of the ISO datetime is sent.

#### What I tried

- I looked at Admin-on-rest's `DateInput` [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#dateinput) and haven't found any option to alter the behaviour.
- I looked at the related Material-UI's [documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker) and the only somewhat relevant option appears to be `DateTimeFormat` but despite a couple of tries I got nowhere.
- I checked other answers, e.g [Material UI Time Picker UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789619/material-ui-time-picker-utc) but cannot figure out how to apply the suggested solution.

Answer (score 7):

Material UI date and timepickers return the local values. You can write a function in their onChange function to reformat the date to any value.

```
  handleTimeInput = (event, time) => {
    this.setState({
      time: time
    })
  }
```

You can then reset the time you send to server by using a simple function like the one below to convert local time to UTC

```
export default (date) => {
  return new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000)
}
```

(for displaying)

```
export default (date) => {
  const tempDate = new Date(date)
  return new Date(tempDate.getTime() - tempDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60000)
}
```

This is the entire component code for my comp.

```
class DateTimePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: null,
      time: null
    };
  }
  handleDateInput = (event, date) => {
    this.setState({
      date: date
    })
  }
  handleTimeInput = (event, time) => {
    this.setState({
      time: time
    })
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const {setSchedule, channel} = this.props
    if (prevState.date !== this.state.date || prevState.time !== this.state.time) {
      if (this.state.date && this.state.time) {
        setSchedule(convertISTtoUTC(concatenateDateAndTime(this.state.date, this.state.time)), channel)
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
          <DatePicker autoOk={true} onChange={this.handleDateInput} />
          <TimePicker autoOk={true} pedantic={true} onChange={this.handleTimeInput} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

With this you have 2 options.

1) you can hook this to redux directly and shoot actions when both are selected.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Actions.html

2) Write your own Input component

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component

Comment: Thanks for your input. It looks like a move in the right direction. What I don't understand though is how to apply this transformation in Admin-on-rest. I have to admit that this very different field of work than I usually do.

Comment: Editing my answer

Comment: At the end I've settled on a different approach but thanks again for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to set a custom function as the `parse` attribute of `<DateInput>` which allows to manipulate the value before going into the Redux storage.

```
const dateString = v => {
  if (isNaN(v)) return;

  let parsedDate = new Date(v);
  let adjustedDate = new Date(parsedDate.getTime() - parsedDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

  return adjustedDate;
};

<DateInput source="your_date" parse={dateString} />
```

This is described in the Admin-on-rest [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#transforming-input-value-tofrom-store) and further information can be found in the Redux form documentation on [Value Lifecycle Hooks](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/ValueLifecycle.md/).

**NOTE**: Credit goes to [kunal pareek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6284861/kunal-pareek) for his suggestion on how to fix the timezone offset in the other advanced answer.

**UPDATE**: This might not be working correctly in the current version (as of 08/2018) of Admin-on-rest. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51667575/772810) by Tomasz Madeyski and/or check the documentation in which the problem has been [addressed](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#dateinput).

Comment: This is almost working, check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51667575/2393077) here

Answer (score 0):

Well, since editing should not change author's intention and it's a bit too long for an edit I'm adding my own answer basing on [tmt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772810/tmt) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44953960/2393077):

Option to use `parse` part is ok but function itself is faulty (see my comments in code to see why):

```
const dateString = v => {
  /* 
  * since v parameter coming is a string then you cannot use isNan 
  * undefined is also coming as a parameter so !v is good equivalent
  */
  if (!v) return; 

  let parsedDate = new Date(v);
  let adjustedDate = new Date(parsedDate.getTime() - parsedDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

  /*
  * since parameter coming in is a string you need to pass string further, that's why I added toISOString() call
  */
  return adjustedDate.toISOString();
};

<DateInput source="your_date" parse={dateString} />
```

Comment: Apparently there have been changes and the problem has been addressed in Admin-on-rest. They now offer their own solution: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#dateinput

Answer (score 0):

Just set moment to specific timezone and intialize material ui picker with moment, and da da.. it will work..

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';
import {DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider} from '@material-ui/pickers';

useEffect(()=>{
    moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Kolkata');
},[])

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={moment} utils={MomentUtils}>
               <DatePicker
                  variant='inline'
                  autoOk
                  label=''
                  disableToolbar
                  disableFuture
                  format='MM/DD/YYYY'
                  value={selectedDay}
                  onChange={(day) => {
                    const date = moment(day).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                    setCurrentDay(date);
                    handleDayChange(day);
                  }}
                  InputProps={{
                    disableUnderline: true,
                    style: {
                      backgroundColor: 'white',
                      paddingLeft: 10,
                      borderRadius: 5,
                      width: 160,
                    },
                    endAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position='end'>
                        <CalendarTodayIcon style={{paddingRight: 8}} />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                />
              </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```